# Left outer join IEnumerable<T> to DataTable - parameter cannot be null error

Tags: c#, linq

I have this:

```
var initialRelease = from c in campaignAvailability
                        where c.reportStatus == "Initial Release"
                        select c;

var results = from server in initialRelease
              join local in table.AsEnumerable()
              on server.campaignId equals local.Field<long>("campaignId") into ls
              from local in ls.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where DateTime.Compare(server.reportDate, local.Field<DateTime>("reportDate")) > 0 || local == null
              select server;

//add it to list of campaigns to process
results.Select(m => new { m.campaignId, m.reportDate }).Distinct()
    .Select(n => new CampaignReportDate() {
        campaignId = n.campaignId,
        reportDate = n.reportDate
    }).ToList().ForEach(c => campaignsToProcess.Add(c));
```

Which I want to look like this in SQL:

```
SELECT a
FROM ienumerable AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table AS b
ON
    a.id = b.id
WHERE b.some_date > a.some_date
    OR b IS NULL
```

I understand that the `where` linq clause can't compare a `null` date.  But, as I understand, the `|| local == null` should have taken care of that.  What am I missing?

Comment: In LINQ (to SQL), `x == null` or `null == x` (where `null` is a *constant expression*) *is* converted to `x is NULL`. There is no restriction on a "null date", excepting as the expression is typed (eg. `DateTime` vs `DateTime?`). In any case, attach the debugger and then break after the materialization of the LINQ. The 'IntelliTrace' will contain the actual generated SQL which will show the actual transformation that occurs.

Comment: @user2864740 Where is the sql?  So it's not `DateTime?` nullable issue?  See:  http://i.imgur.com/2OYpG3S.png  What else am I missing?

Comment: Oh .. DataTable. LINQ to Objects, not LINQ to SQL/Entities (there will be no SQL generated) .. the exception is probably thrown by `local.Field<DateTime>("reportDate")` when the column contains a null value. In any case, make sure the *text* of such exceptions is included in questions.

Comment: I don't think I'm doing anything special.  In `results`, I just want to do some filtering based on the `where` condition.  Then I want to add results to a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  `local` was coming in as `null` and I still needed a way to compare it to `server.reportDate`.  I used a ternary operator.  And because I was assigning `DateTime.MinValue` as the default date, I was able to remove `|| local == null`.

```
where DateTime.Compare(server.reportDate, (local != null) ? (DateTime)local["reportDate"] : DateTime.MinValue) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing left joins in linq to objects, you should prefer providing a default value when empty. Then your query doesn't have to make much changes.

```
var results =
    from server in initialRelease
    join local in table.AsEnumerable()
        on server.campaignId equals local.Field<long>("campaignId") into ls
    from local in ls.DefaultIfEmpty(table.NewRow())
    where DateTime.Compare(server.reportDate,
            local.Field<DateTime?>("reportDate") ?? Datetime.MaxValue) > 0
    select server;
```